# Excel: Advanced search and replace based on content

Tags: excel, replace

In an excel sheet, I have three columns.

- Column A contains the word of interest.
- Column B contains the definition.
- Column C contains an example sentence.

Sun | the star around which the earth orbits | we sat outside in the sun

I would like to replace the word in column C (example sentence) with three dots (...) to create a close deletion flashcard.

1. copy the word from cell A1 "Sun"
2. select column C1
3. replace the same word "Sun" with three dots (...)
4. move to cell A2
5. copy word in cell A2
6. move to cell C2
7. replace the same word with three dots (...)
8. move to cell A3

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Excel, this is why I didn't include code!

Comment: The point is that you "tried" something first, then post what you have tried and get help with code.  SO is not intended to provide full solutions. (I posted a solution below because this one is just three lines of code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FORMULA SOLUTION**

A simple formula solution would require a new column with the following code:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C1,A1,"…")
```

Result with formula in 'D' column:

[image]

---

**VBA SOLUTION**

Loop through each cell in range and replace the word of interest like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A3")
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Replace(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value, cell.Value, "...")
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

Tested with data that looked like this:

[image]

After running the macro it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Worked awesome. Many thanks and next time I will do my best to post some code. Appreciate your time.